# Unit test with database access

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I m developing a REST api and  I'm actually trying to write unit tests to familiarise with them. I'm actually using Mocha on a NodeJS homemade micro-framework.

### ------------------------First part--------------------

I know how to test a method that returns data from comparisons, calculations, but I don't know how to test a method that returns objects from a database call.

And I don't know how to test objects that get other complex objects as parameters.

For example, I'm actually having a parent class called "Service". Some other services extend this class.

In the Service class, I inject an entity manager (which deals with the db) in the constructor MANUALLY (I'm using CoffeeScript, and don't use an IOC container).

Now, how can I get an instance of my Service in my unit test that accepts an EntityManager instance?

### ------------------------Second part--------------------

I've read a bit about mock objects. But should I create my own mock objects ?
I mean, creating the exact same object but with an other behaviour?
Like not calling a database object but a predefined list?

Is this not too long?

Abstraction should be great to make it works (no interfaces in javascript, am I wrong?)

Comment: A unit test should never touch a database, since a database is an external resource that doesn't run in-memory. Unit tests should be fast, small and isolated. The only reason a unit test should ever fail is because you have a bug in your business logic, not because your web server is misconfigured or because someone moved the db file on disk.